# Plotting and finding roots of bessel functions

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

I am trying to plot roots of a function that is composed of multiple bessel functions being added and multiplied in Matlab.  The equation is Jm(omega)*Ik(omega)+Im(omega)*Jk(omega) where Jm is the bessel function of the first kind of order m (besselj). Im is the modified bessel function of the first kind of order m (besseli).  For each mode m=o,1,2,...and n=1,2,3...  The frequency omega(mn) is the corresponding root of the listed equation. m=0,1,2 n-1,2,3,4.  I need to solve the equation for the 12 roots.  I am new to Matlab and this is a little out of my league. So far I have this code but I wasn't sure if I needed the variable omega in the script or not.  I have also looked at other people's questions on the suject but didn't see any quite like this.  The plots I have seen look nothing like mine which tells me I am probably wrong.  Thanks for any help.

```
m=(0:2); k=(1:3); n=(1:4);
Jm=besselj(m,n');
Ik=besseli(k,n');
Jk=besselj(k,n');
Im=besseli(m,n');
g=Jm.*Ik+Im.*Jk
plot(g)
```

Comment: Try to use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plotting**

`besselj` and `besseli` take what you call `omega` as their second parameter, so to plot your function you should try something like

```
m=0; k=1; omega=0:0.02:10;
Jm=besselj(m,omega);
Ik=besseli(k,omega);
Jk=besselj(k,omega);
Im=besseli(m,omega);
g=Jm.*Ik+Im.*Jk;
plot(omega,g);
hold all;
plot(omega,0,'k');
axis([min(omega) max(omega) -100 100]);
```

This shows you that for `m=1, k=1` the first zeros are around 3.2, 6.3 and 9.4:

[image: screenshot matlab figure]

**Finding the roots numerically**

You could implement [Halley's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) for your function `g`, similar to how the roots of `besselj` are determined in the [MatlabCentral file linked by Cheery](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6794).