# Equation solving containing besselj

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

In Matlab how we find `a` in `J0(ax)=0` where `J0` is bessel function of first kind and zero order, and `x` is a known vector?

How we can find `a` as a vector?

Comment: You tagged your question as "equation solving", but there is only 1 follower. You might want to add more tags.

Comment: See [Plotting and finding roots of bessel functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9339199/2604213).

Answer (score 0):

If the x vector is not massive, perhaps this inefficient way would work?

```
syms a;
for i = 1:length(x)
    rt(i) = solve(besselj(0,a*x(i)),a);
end
avec = double(rt);
```